# How do I integrate media (e.g. attaching audio) to nodes?

Tags: 8, media, files

I installed the [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) module for Drupal 8. I thought it would somehow facilitate adding Mp3, etc, as [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) does in Drupal 7, where I could specify a media player type for an audio file. (And things work fairly well.) I am updating my site to Drupal 8 and it seems the Media Entity module only acts as an API. Maybe I just need to wait for an official Drupal 8 release before I get too far in the weeds with media?

Since I am grabbing Mp3 files from my previous site, ideally there would be a media field to which I can, in code, just add the field info, with the rendering of the field being determined by the form display settings.

Anyway, I am sure a lot of people are trying to figure this out in Drupal 8, so if anyone has a good approach, I am all ears!

Comment: ummm... I don't see a Drupal 8 version available on the media module page... unless core comes with media?

Comment: I edited my post - I was confusing Media with Media Entity

Comment: The module just provides the connection  between  dual and the media. For managing  media files you have to do it on your own what  means you have to code your module and relay on media entity's api. So if you are no coder you should just wait until media for d8 is ready to go.

Comment: I can code but that seems like it would be a big effort, especially if the media module is on its way. I guess I will wait.

Answer (score 0):

To use mp3 files with Media entity you need the additional module "Media entity audio".

Alternatively, you can attach audio straight to nodes with the "Audiofield" module.